# Error: "Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop"

Tags: reactjs

how to prevent this error?

> Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop
>
> my code

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";

const Dropdown = ({ options, selected, onSelectedChange }) => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const ref = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    const onBodyClick = (event) => {
      if (ref.current.contains(event.target)) {
        return;
      }
      setOpen(false);
    };
    document.body.addEventListener("click", onBodyClick, { capture: true });

    return () => {
      document.body.removeEventListener("click", onBodyClick, {
        capture: true,
      });
    };
  }, []);
```

i believe the only thing causes it to re-render is the useEffect i tried to delete it and run the app again and the same error!

Comment: `i tried to delete it and run the app again and the same error!` Sounds like the error is caused by a different piece of code then. The code you've shown looks fine to me.

Comment: this is the app component code : ```
const App = () => {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(options[0]);
  const [dropDown, setdropDown] = useState(true);

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={setdropDown(!dropDown)}>toggle dropdown</button>
      {dropDown ? (
        <Dropdown
          selected={selected}
          options={options}
          onSelectedChange={setSelected}
        />
      ) : null}
    </div>
  );
};

export default App; ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw the problem is you call `setdropDown` when render the component. So this error occurs. You just update like this:

```
<button onClick={() => setdropDown(!dropDown)}>
```